# undefined is not an object in route react native

Tags: react-native

i have created a component listing detail screen and listitem in list item it has a card when  person click on card it display listingDetailScreen same happen when click  suddenly i want to make a bottom tab navigator and in bottom tab navigator i have passed component listing details but it through an error undefined is not an object here is my code of list screen

```
const listings = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Close your eyes",
    price: 10,
    image: require("../assets/child.png"),
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "dare to surrender",
    price: 15,
    image: require("../assets/blur.png"),
  },
];
export default function ListingsScreens({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <ExpoScreen style={styles.screen}>
      <FlatList
        data={listings}
        keyExtractor={(listings) => listings.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <CardList
            title={item.title}
            subtitle={"$" + item.price}
            image={item.image}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ListingDetails", item)}
          />
        )}
      />
    </ExpoScreen>
  );
}
```

here is my Screendetailscreen

```
export default function ListingDetailsScreen({ route }) {
  console.log(route);
  const listing = route.params;
  return (
    <View style={styles.Screen}>
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <Image style={styles.CardImage} source={listing.image} />

        <View style={styles.tittleContainer}>
          <AppText style={styles.title}>{listing.title}</AppText>
          <AppText style={styles.subtitle}>{listing.price}</AppText>
        </View>
      </View>
      <ListItem
        image={require("../assets/dummyFemale.png")}
        title="Anna bella"
        sutitle="suck 5 person blood"
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

in this i have made a tab navigator

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const AppNavigation = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedNavigator} />
    <Tab.Screen name="ListingEdit" component={ListingDetailsScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={AccountNavigator} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
);

export default AppNavigation;
```

this are three tab all are working accept mid one
[image]

when I click this it gives me error of
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Tab.Screen name="ListingEdit" component={ListingDetailsScreen} />
```

This will navigate to `ListingDetailsScreen` without any params,

You can try passing params when you call `ListingDetailsScreen`  from `<Tab.Navigator>`:

Try doing:

```
<Tab.Screen 
  name="ListingEdit"
  component={() => <ListingDetailsScreen route={{ params: ITEM }} />}
/>
```

But again, you will have to find a way to get your ITEM in `AppNavigation` so you can pass it as props.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with getParams.
Ex: route.getParams('parameter_name').
If not working, you need to confirm using this code.

```
console.log(route)
```

Or
console.log(JSON.stringfy(route))
As result, you can check correct route is returned or not.
After check, you can get correct parameter from route object.
Hope to your success.

Comment: Object {
  "key": "ListingEdit-oK0Wojum1iGcbBIxCnxNV",
  "name": "ListingEdit",
  "params": undefined,
}

Comment: this is my console.log

Comment: As you can see, params is undefined.
So you need to check route definition part.

Comment: this route is working in stack navigatoe but through error in tab

Comment: Did you check navigation file carefully?